# Multi-processing functions to cores and threads

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have written a program that determines if a Mersenne prime is prime or not based on the Lucas-Lehmer sequence. I'm want to use multi-processing and/or multi-threading to decrease the amount of time it takes to check if prime, and thus i researched into other posts and tutorials here and on Youtube, however the examples often use vastly different implementations; regardless of whether they are using the 'thread' or the 'threading' module and typically only feature one function. How do i go about paralleling 2 of my functions; which take different times to compute and need to return there calculation to the 3rd function for the final result.(please note i have only started programming recently). I am aware of optimisations to the algorithm itself i could make; if the last digit of the Mersenne prime is even or 5 for example then it should just print not prime, but i want to focus on the paralleling specifically. Thanks. Code:

```
import time


def MersennePrime(pm=3):
    mp = (2 ** pm) - 1
    print(pm)
    print(mp)
    while pm <=25:
        pm = pm + 1
        print(mp)


def LucasLehmerSequence(n=4):
    lls = (n ** 2) - 2 # Calculates the 2nd digit of the Lucas-Lehmer Sequence.
    print(n)
    print(lls)
    while pm <= 25:
        n = lls
        lls = (n ** 2) - 2
        print(lls)


def Checker(pm=3, n=4):
    start = time.time()
    mp = (2 ** pm) - 1
    while pm <= 25:
        lls = (n ** 2) - 2
        n = lls # Updates the value of n to be = the previous sequence entry.
        lls = (n ** 2) - 2
        pm = pm + 1 # Adds 1 to the power of the Mersenne.
        mp = (2 ** pm) - 1
        if (lls % mp) == 0: # If nth in sequence has a remainder of 0 when / by the nth Mersenne it is a Mersenne Prime.
            print(str(mp) + ' is prime.')
        else:
            print(str(mp) + ' is not prime')
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)


print(Checker())
```

Working paralleled code, i simplified the 3 functions down into one:

```
def Checker(pm_n=(2, 4)):
pm, n = pm_n
lls = (n ** 2 - 2)
lls = n
lls = (n ** 2 - 2)
mp  = (2 ** pm - 1)
pm = pm + 1
mp  = (2 ** pm - 1)
if (lls % mp == 0):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    with Pool(4) as pool:
        pm1 = 2
        n1 = 4
        pm2 = 3
        n2 = (n1 ** 2 - 2)
        pm3 = 4
        n3 = (n2 ** 2 - 2)
        pm4 = 5
        n4 = (n3 ** 2 - 2)
        result = pool.map(Checker, [(pm1, n1), (pm2, n2), (pm3, n3), (pm4, n4)])
        print(result)
        while True:
            pm1 = pm4 + 1
            n1 = (n4 ** 2 - 2)
            pm2 = pm1 + 1
            n2 = (n1 ** 2 - 2)
            pm3 = pm2 + 1
            n3 = (n2 ** 2 - 2)
            pm4 = pm3 + 1
            n4 = (n3 ** 2 - 2)
            result = pool.map(Checker, [(pm1, n1), (pm2, n2), (pm3, n3), (pm4, n4)])
            print(result)

The Output will be True for Prime and False for not Prime in an array 4 long. Then whether the next 4 numbers are prime will be output in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use threads.  Python has a global interpreter lock, so multithreading will be slower than single threading.  Multiprocessing could help, although your best bet will be to run multiple `Checker`s in parallel.  Most of the examples you find will use a multiprocessing pool.  It would look like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    with Pool(4) as pool:
        result = pool.map(Checker, [(pm1, n1), (pm2, n2), (pm3, n3), (pm4, n4)])
        print(result)
```

This will run the checker four times in parallel.

Edit: However, this might still be slower than serial execution, unless you're asking for a significant amount of computation to be done in each check.

Edit: Show how to guard execution of the multiprocessing stuff.

Comment: The following error is thrown:   File "C:\Users\kierp\OneDrive\Documents\Mersenne Prime Checker.py", line 40, in <module>
    result = pool.map(Checker, [(pm1, n1), (pm2, n2), (pm3, n3), (pm4, n4)])
NameError: name 'pm1' is not defined                             I'm assuming this means that i need to create variables: pm1, n1, etc?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I should have been more clear about that.  I wasn't sure what you wanted to send to the checker, so those are placeholder variable names.  You'd write `pm1=3` before calling `map`.  Also, there's another mismatch between my code and yours, which is that my code sends a single argument (a tuple of two values) while yours expects two arguments (two separate values).  You can square this by changing `Checker` to take a single argument called `pm_n` and then on the first line of the function assigning it to `pm` and `n` like this. `pm, n = pm_n`.

Comment: i've done the following: if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(4) as pool:
        pm1 = 3
        pm2 = 4
        pm3 = 5
        pm4 = 6
        n1 = 4
        n2 = (n1 ** 2 - 2)
        n3 = (n2 ** 2 - 2)
        n4 = (n3 ** 2 - 2)
        result = pool.map(Checker, [(pm1, n1), (pm2, n2), (pm3, n3), (pm4, n4)])       but the result is printed 4 times in  a row, and at the start the results are printed randomly - i assume due to the processes not all initialising at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, everything is happening at the same time, you're going to want to return `True` or `False` from `Checker`, then everything in `result` is in the order it was input.

Comment: (Rather than printing directly from `Checker`, that is.)

Comment: Thanks, Hopefully this will be my last comment haha: I've converted the Tuple and changed the print(str(mp) + ' is prime.'), etc with return True, else: return False. However, when i call result via print(result) at the end of the program i get multiple, repeated name errors: NameError: name 'result' is not defined. And when the function call is used instead: print(Checker()) . False is printed 5 times. How can i rectify this? Many thanks :)

Comment: Ah, things will go a bit haywire if you don't protect the multiprocessing stuff.  Create an entrypoint so that it only gets executed once: `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: Inside the entrypoint, put the multiprocessing import and the `with` block.  Also try printing your result inside the `with` block.